# Can't delete sqlite row

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete a row of a listview that get values from a db sqlite. the delete method is this one:

```
 public boolean deleteRow(long id) {
        String where  = "WHERE " + DataBaseWrapper.APP_ID + "=" + id;
        return database.delete(DataBaseWrapper.SC_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
    }
```

i tried two way now and none works; the first was use the `OnItemLongClickListener` in my fragment in this way

```
lvTest.setLongClickable(true);
        lvTest.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                shOperations.deleteRow(id);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But seems that doesn't do anything.. i tried to put some logs but they not showing up. I also tried set the return to `true` without success.. the other way was from the adapter; in getView method i wrote this:

```
mViewHolder.tvTitle.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            ShortcutsOperations scOperations = new ShortcutsOperations(DrawerActivity.instance);
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                scOperations.deleteRow(getItemId(position));
                return false;
            }
        });
```

but nothing change.. which could be the problem?

Comment: How are you confirming that the record is not being deleted? It does not look like you are checking the return value of deleteRow(id), does it return true or false?

Comment: mmh, what do you mean?

Comment: `WHERE` in Android sqlite convenience method `whereArgs` would result in a syntax error. Your click listener is not firing since you are not reporting an exception for the syntax problem.

Comment: somy delete method is wrong?

Comment: even removing the "WHERE" it's not working

Comment: What is the return value of the `delete()` method when you call it?

Comment: should be return true if you mean this..i don't know i tried every solution and none worked!i think the only one way is from the getView method

Comment: It returns the number of rows affected, in your case you would be expecting it to return `1`.  Can you check if it's returning `0`?  I guess check that `deleteRow()` returns true;

Comment: ok, now i'm getting you.. seems return 0 by the way